# Create a cloudwatch metric on a log

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Trying to create a cloudwatch metric from a cloudwatch log, but cant workout the syntax to return the value instead of count the key.

given a log with a log value like:

```
{"log":"2023-07-23T20:34:04.81555193Z stdout F {\"service\":\"test\",\"event\":\"batch_indexing_job\",\"index\":\"data-object\",\"total_count\":57,\"error_count\":0,\"duration\":0.14786760200513527}"
```

i thought to return the a '57' for 'total_count' i would use: '{$.log = "*total_count*" }'

but if i use test pattern in cloudwatch i get no results (or deploying it).

Any idea how to resolve?